# JSP print Array with JSP

Tags: java, arrays, jsp

I am trying to make a rolodex style JSP. I am using a java class with the JSP and am not allowed to use a servlet or anything else really. I am unable to keep an added entry. When I go to my add entries page and add a person the count goes up one. Then if I go to the "home" page it starts back at whatever I have set up for debugging. Also if I try to add a second person the count won't go up again.

Here is the flow of what happens:

start with 4 persons  --> Add 1st person --> count is 5 persons-->
hit home page link--> count is 4 persons

start with 4 persons --> Add 1st person --> count is 5 persons -->
add 2d person --> count is 5 persons

Here is the java class I have:

```
package Cards;


 import java.util.ArrayList;
 import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;


  public class Card {

  private final ArrayList<Line> entries = new ArrayList<>();
  private int entrySequenceId = 0; // to give each entry a unique id

  public Card() {
  }

  public ArrayList<Line> getEntries() {
  return entries;
 }

  public void modifyEntry(int entryIndex, String phoneNumber) {
  if (entryIndex >= 0 && entryIndex < entries.size()) {
  entries.get(entryIndex).phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
 }
 }

 public void addEntry(String name, String phoneNumber) {
  entries.add(new Line(name, phoneNumber));
 }

  public ArrayList<Line> search(String searchText) {
   searchText = searchText.toLowerCase();
   ArrayList<Line> matches = new ArrayList<>();
  for (Line entry : entries) {
   if (entry.name.toLowerCase().contains(searchText)) {
    matches.add(entry);
    }
  }
  return matches;
 }

  public Line getEntry(String id) {
  int entryId = Integer.valueOf(id);
  for (Line line : entries) {
  if (line.getEntryId() == entryId) {
    return line;
  }
  }
  return null;
  }

  public static Card getCardFromRequest(HttpServletRequest request) {
  Card card = (Card) request.getSession().getAttribute("Card");
  if (card == null) {
   card = new Card();
  // for debug, hard coding of some entries - 2 of the same first name 2   sets of the 
    //same last name 2 of the same number and 2 with speacail characters
   card.entries.add(card.new Line("Luis Ramos", "4772662"));
   card.entries.add(card.new Line("Allison Ramos", "4772662"));
   card.entries.add(card.new Line("Meg Ryan", "1-800-999-9999"));
  card.entries.add(card.new Line("Luis Ryan", "1-8"));
  request.getSession().setAttribute("card", card);
  }
  return card;
 }

  public class Line {

   private String name;
   private String phoneNumber;
   private final int entryId;

   public Line(String name, String phoneNumber) {
  this.name = name;
  this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
   this.entryId = Card.this.entrySequenceId++;
  }

    public int getEntryId() {
   return entryId;
   }

   public String getName() {
   return name;
   }

   public void setName(String name) {
   this.name = name;
   }

   public String getPhoneNumber() {
  return phoneNumber;
  }

   public void setPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) {
  this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    }

 }
}
```

And here is the my Add JSP:

```
     <%@page import="java.util.ArrayList"%>
     <%@page import="Cards.Card"%>

     <%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>

     <!DOCTYPE html>

     <html>

     <head>

     <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

     <title>Rolodex</title>

     </head>

     <body bgcolor="lightgray">

     <%

      Card card = Card.getCardFromRequest(request);
       String name = request.getParameter("name");
      if (name != null && name.length() != 0) {
        card.addEntry(name, request.getParameter("phoneNumber"));
      }
      %>
     <center>

       <%
         out.println("There are " + card.getEntries().size() + " entries.<br/>");
     %>

        <form action="Add.jsp">Name:<input type="text" name="name"/>    <br/>Phone number:<input type="text" name="phoneNumber"/><input     type="submit" value="Add"/></form>

    <br/>

    <a href="Index.jsp">Home</a>

     </center>

 </body>

</html>
```

This is an assignment however, the assignment has been turned in and graded. I now just want to improve my understanding. Sometimes I want to have stuff happens that is not going to work. I would not be surprised if someone tells me that I need some kind of database in order to save the information.
If anyone could point to me where my mistake is or tell me why it won't stay I would be very grateful.

Comment: How do you run/deploy your application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your method `getCardFromRequest` you get your card object from `getSession().getAttribute("Card")` but when you update it and put it back to session you put it back like this `getSession().setAttribute("card", card)` you should call setAttribute like this `setAttribute("Card", card)` so you put and retrieve same object from session

Comment: So simple, and yet I missed it. I won't tell you how long I spent looking at this trying to figure it out.  I also see how I messed up in the method, which is always my goal. Thank you so much for the help.